# iOS and android with the same programming language

Tags: android, ios

I am wondering if i can write the code for android, IOS, Linux at the same time, using the same programming language. Maybe C? I am doing a project on that and can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if my or igoris's answer solved your issue please remember to up vote or mark as top answer or add comments if it didn't. Others facing the same issue would appreciate knowing how you solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is shared by both but its very complicated and requires a huge indepth knowledge of both platforms and API's, also the UI can't be created with C as they both differ hugely in how to display data / controls. The result would be a C library to use in both and java / objective-c for the front ends.

If you have to do it with 1 code base i'd recommend a thrid party hybrid solution such as phonegap which is essentially a website wrapped up in a native webview with a few hooks into some native functionality. or Appcelerators titanium which you write apps in javascript that allow you to use there library to access native controls / API's.

I've used Titanium before and find it quite good, android can be a little buggy from time to time

Answer (score 0):

You can use some mono-based soltion. [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) for example. Or you can embed Mono into your application yourself. You will not be able to create interfaces or access some device-specific features but you can code your business logic in c# and use it anywhere.